# My loop is not continuing with the next step

Tags: java

I have a problem with my loop

```
public static void me() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
    int mew = 0;
    double mes = 0;
    boolean Curve = true;
    int cBool = 0;
    double cNum = 0;
    double mers = 0;
    double wmes = 0;

    //Input Midterm weight and score
    System.out.println("\nMidterm exam:");
    System.out.print("\tWhat is its weight (0-100)? ");
    mew = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\tExam Score ");
    mes = input.nextDouble();
    while (Curve){
        System.out.print("\tWas there a curve? (1 for yes, 2 for no) ");
        cBool = input.nextInt();
        if (cBool == 2)
            Curve = false;
        else
        System.out.print("\tHow much was the curve? ");
        cNum = input.nextDouble();
        Curve = false;
    }

    //calculate weighted Midterm score
    mers = (mes+cNum);
    if (mers > 100)
            mers = 100;
    wmes = ((mers/100)*mew);
    System.out.println("\tWeighted Exam score: " + df.format(wmes));}
}
```

The problem is when i enter 2 for cBool it will not continue to the next step, however if i enter 1 for cBool then give a number for cNum it will continue with the next step

Comment: You're setting `Curve = false;` to exit the while loop anyway after first iteration.

Comment: From the code you have are already setting Curve = false when cBool == 2. So it wont continue further, you rloop will only run once for anyinput

Comment: Moreover if the else part is a compound statement enclose it in braces.  else{
        System.out.print("\tHow much was the curve? ");
        cNum = input.nextDouble();
        Curve = false;
}

Comment: ALWAYS use `{` and `}` after your `if` and `else` lines.  Otherwise, you get unexpected results like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to isolate all the instructions existing in the else block ? 
From this:

```
else
System.out.print("\tHow much was the curve? ");
cNum = input.nextDouble();
Curve = false;
```

TO THIS :

```
else
```

**{**

```
 System.out.print("\tHow much was the curve? ");
    cNum = input.nextDouble();
    Curve = false;
```

**}**

Comment: Would this iterate? What would be required when the input is `3` or `1`? Would the loop even be needed then?